# Grails Changing location of 'i18n' folder

Tags: grails, localization, message

I want to change the location of the grails-app/i18n folder, such that it can be specified on development/production environment.

How and where can I configure this?

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Comment: version is grails 2.3.6